# Facebook Open Graph PHP Extract Username

Tags: php, api, sdk, facebook-opengraph

I have been searching high and low on this website and others and just can't seem to get the answer.

I am using the open graph and facebook.php and I can extract everything from the api except the username.

Suggestions on this site have not been what I'm after and they usually just end up extracting the User ID. I need the username.

So using the simple method of:

```
$user_username = $facebook->api('/me?fields=username');
print_r($user_username);
```

Which displays on my site:

```
Array
(
[username] => MyUsername
[id] => MyID
)
```

But I can't get any code to pull just the username value from the array.

Comment: How about `echo 'Your username is: ' $user_username['username'];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the array, you need some more basic php knowlegde I think:

```
$user_username = $user_username["username"]
```